# How to force one app to stay on the last screen?

Tags: fullscreen, expose

I'm always using full-screen apps, and I like to have the Terminal app "sticky" as a last application on the carousel.

Whenever a new app is opened in full-screen, it take this last place and I have to rearrange the app using Expose.

Any suggestion?

Comment: If you want a screen to always have the same positioning, make it the first (left-most) screen instead. this way it will always be in the same location

Comment: It's a good idea, but in this way I will have to go through the "terminal screen" every time that I switch from the desktop to the full screen apps. It will be nice to find a way to put the new opened full screen apps always as a left-most app

Comment: Ahh, on El Capitan, you can have any space be left-most. So I can have Terminal as left-most, then Desktop1, then Safari, then Mail.

Comment: Wow :) never noticed that we can also have fullscreens app on the left :P